# Why does ln -s accept a single argument

Tags: symlink, coreutils, ln

```
> cd /tmp
> ln -s foo
> ls -alhF /tmp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user    3 Jul 29 14:00 foo -> foo
```

Is this a bug in `ln` or is there a use case for symlinking a file to itself?

This is with `coreutils 8.21-1ubuntu5.1`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's not a bug. The use case is for when you want to link a file to the same basename but in a different directory:

```
cd /tmp
ln -s /etc/passwd
ls -l passwd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xxx xxx 11 Jul 29 09:10 passwd -> /etc/passwd
```

It's true that when you do this with a filename that is in the same directory it creates a link to itself which does not do a whole lot of good!

This works regardless of whether you use symlinks or hard links.

Comment: Another way to put it: `ln -s /path/to/file` is short for `ln -s /path/to/file .`. Like `ls` is short for `ls .`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, and you save two whole keystrokes! :-)

Comment: Note that that behaviour is not specified by POSIX but seems to be fairly common (GNU, busybox, FreeBSD, Solaris, Ultrix at least, and was already like that (though -s wasn't supported of course) in the first version of Unix in the early 70s).

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to find out of course, is to try it and see. When no 2nd argument is given, `ln` will create a link in the current directory with the same name as the original:

```
$ ln -s /etc
$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon         4 Jul 29 16:09 etc -> /etc
```

This is also explained in `man ln`:

> In the 2nd form, create a link to TARGET in the current directory.

The "2nd form" refers to:

> ln [OPTION]... TARGET                  (2nd form)